# Why is my dotnet core project re-compling?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have two very similar dotnet core REST API's. When I go to deploy them, one runs without issue. However, the other one prints the following message to the log before locking the machine:

```
Project app (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because 
the version or bitness of the CLI changed since the last build
```

What causes the recompile to be triggered? And why might only one of these two projects trigger a recompile? Can I prevent this at all? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I've left out any critical information.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "before locking the machine?"

Comment: What version of the .NET SDK are you using?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Thanks for the answer, it's been helpful to rule out a few things. Both apps are running in docker containers using version 1.0.0-preview2-003131 and both global.json files specify that version to be used. I've verified that both containers are using the same versions, yet one logs that it was previously complied while the other needs to recompile. When it tries to recompile it throttles the CPU on that machine to the point where the machine is unusable (apologies, "locked" was not a clear adjective to use). Any thoughts?

Comment: When you run `dotnet --info` on both Docker containers, do both show the same runtime identifier (RID)? For instance, mine right now says `win10-x64`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I've just confirmed both packages have the same RID: `RID:         debian.8-x64`. However, this is likely different than the location where the containers are run. I've been trying to get confirmation of that but the machine keeps freezing when I run `dotnet --info`. Nevertheless, doesn't yet explain why only one image works.

Comment: I'm thinking this may be the issue: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19166
I'm using the following kernal to build: 4.4.0-21-generic

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

> What causes the recompile to be triggered?

The recompile occurs when the version and/or bitness (x86 or x64) of the .NET Core command line interface (CLI) changes between building and running the program.

From the command line, find the version by running `dotnet --version` and find the bitness by running `dotnet --info`.

> And why might only one of these two projects trigger a recompile?

It depends on your specific setup. One of your projects is building with a different version/bitness of the CLI than the version that is running it.

> Can I prevent this at all?

For a given project, build and run with the same CLI version/bitness. You can control this with the [`global.json` file's sdk.version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/global-json) property or by having only one version of the CLI installed.

## Some Details

You can recreate your error locally, if you have more than one version of the .NET CLI installed. For instance, and assuming you have both of the following versions installed, create and build a new dotnet core app using CLI version `1.0.0-preview2-003156` and then run it using CLI version `1.0.0-preview2-003133`.

PowerShell:

```
cd C:/
New-Item -type Directory foobar
cd foobar
Add-Content -Path global.json -Value '{ "sdk" : { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003156" }}'
dotnet new 
dotnet restore
dotnet build
Clear-Content -Path global.json
Add-Content -Path global.json -Value '{ "sdk" : { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003133" }}'
dotnet run
```

Output:

> Project foobar (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because the version or bitness of the CLI changed since the last build